# Cypress - Clicking overlapping elements

Tags: cypress

I'm migrating all module tests of a React Redux Web Application from WebDriverIo to Cypress and found this weird scenario.

I have a table with a series of elements. Clicking on one of them opens a window on the side showing more detailed data. The test I am trying to migrate is one that checks that the window with detailed data remains visible and without altering its data despite any changes I make to the table's search filters. Even if that means discarding the item whose detailed data is currently visible.

Problem? The detail view covers the filters and Cypress doesn't seem to like this and gives me trouble detecting the selectors. For example, imagine this is my table and the black square is the place the detail view will take. (The photo was taken from Internet).

[image]

I did several tests with those filters so I know the way I'm doing to access the selectors is the correct one. But, as it keeps behind Cypress is having trouble finding them.

I tried to access filters after closing the detail view and, of course, it worked. Also tried adding the param `{force:true}` in the `.click()` action but it also failed.

Somebody has ever faced a similar scenario? Thanks in advance

Comment: How does a user change the search query when there is an element on top of the search bar?

Comment: +1 to what vault said -- I don't think this is a realistic scenario a user could do, and I'm not sure the test adds significant value to your test suite.

Comment: I agree with both of you guys. For me I would delete them. But as you may guess, I have a boss that only wants the migration done. I tried to explain but...